Why can't i place loop cut on certain faces of my object?
I'm trying to model a gun in blender, using loop cuts to allign my object with a reference photo in the background. After modeling for a few minutes i realized that there are certain faces on the gun that i can't place loop cuts on.
Why is this happening and how can i fix this?

hello you can't create loopcuts across faces that are not quads, so you either need to correct your topology, or use the knife tool to create your edge loop (K to activate, A to cut orthogonally, C to cut through)
